# How do I concat two dataframes on top of one another using a common column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes which share the same column names and have overlapping entries in one of the columns. I'd like to append one on the bottom of another, and merge on the common entries in the specified column.

Eg, Column 'Date' has the same entries in both dataframes, but in DataFrame B there are rows in this column which are not present in DataFrame A.

Comment: add an example and code

Comment: and a representation of the desired output please

Comment: You're probably looking to do a "join" (an **outer** join) or a "merge". Now you know the terms, you can probably just google it (there are plenty of examples on here, some of which might have popped up as you wrote your question).

Answer (score 0):

You can either use concat or append for this case.

Append:

appending second dataframe to first dataframe

```
df = first.append(second)
# you must reset the index
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

concat:

```
pd.concat([noclickDF, clickDF], ignore_index=True, sort=True)
```